# Does an interaction free measurent of an object in superposition collapse its wavefunction?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, measurements, superposition, interactions

I was recently thinking about the Elitzur-Vaidman bomb experiment or interaction free measurement and the nature of the measurement of a superposition.

So what would happen if the bomb we are measuring with the Mach-Zehnder interferometer like in the Elitzur-Vaidman scheme is in a spatial superposition state itself? Would its wavefunction collapse like in a measurement with interaction or would the superposition state of the bomb not be affected at all?

1. In case the wavefunction collapses, how does it? Reading about measurements it is often said that the collapse is caused by an interaction, but in the Elitzur-Vaidman experiment we don't actually interact with the particle.
2. In case the wavefunction does not collapse and the spatial superposition state of the bomb remains unchanged, one could simultaneously measure both possible location, but not find the bomb - meaning that the bomb is non-existent?

Comment: I read  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elitzur%E2%80%93Vaidman_bomb_tester . The no-interaction is a moot point, as all meassurements involve interactions and because it is quantum mechancis it gives a probability of 50% of the bomb beig detonated. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elitzur%E2%80%93Vaidman_bomb_tester .

Comment: @annav the probability can be lowered arbitrarily, the 50% version is just the simplest to illustrate the principle. But indeed, the interaction is still there, just not obvious when looking at it classically.